# how do i validate regex for dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create regex validation for address which allow minimum 15 character and maximum 9999,
also its allow Number, Letters, and specific special character, also have required at least one letter

in Special character I need to allow space( /s), Comma (,), Single coat(') and dash (-),
all three are working fine but dash (-) is break all other invalid regex

Can you please let me know how can archive this solution

I am trying to below regex from [https://regex101.com](https://stackoverflow.com)

`^((?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-]){15,9999})$`

A81Seventh paradise, delhi,
A81 Seventh's paradise, delhi,
A-81 Seventh paradise, delhi,
A#81 Seventh paradise, delhi,
A-8,
-81,

Comment: fixed using this regex ^((?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-]){10,9999})$

Comment: Your link to regex101 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is:

`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-]){15,9999}$`

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WyXaJr/2)

Your original regex was requiring that at *every* character position there would be at least one letter that follows instead of checking only at the beginning of the string -- and that can never be possible.